# Getting 200 random fields from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have 100K tweets stored in MongoDB. Each tweet is stored like the following:

```
{
    "_id" : "123456789",
    "user_screenName " : "john doe",
    "text" : "some tweet"
}
```

I have found http://bdadam.com/blog/finding-a-random-document-in-mongodb.html and [MongoDB: how to find 10 random document in a collection of 100?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806721/mongodb-how-to-find-10-random-document-in-a-collection-of-100) but not sure if this is exactly what I need.

I want to get 200 random `text` fields so I can analyze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/) stage for that.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $sample: { size: 200 } // select 200 random documents
}, {
    $project: {
        "_id": 0, // exclude "_id"
        "text": 1 // include "text"
    }
})
```

Also, [MongoDB Compass](https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/master/schema/) provides quite some nice functionality around analyzing existing data.