# getting random n record not wroking

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
function get() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        Card.find([
            { $sample: {size: 3} }, 
            { $match:  {"deckId": req.body.deckId} }
        ]).exec(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve(result)
            }
        });

    });
}
```

It gives me all data but i need only 3 random data. i have google about get random N no of data but why not working for me?

Comment: Try using `aggregate` instead of `find` here and have a look at a very similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24806721/mongodb-how-to-find-10-random-document-in-a-collection-of-100).

Comment: @vahdet but now $match not wroking for me?

Comment: deckId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Decks',
        required: 'Please Provide Deck'
    }
My deckId schema

Comment: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.deckId) solve my problem

Comment: Never mix callback and promise, you can simply `return Card.find(...).exec()` to return the promise.

Answer (score 0):

```
function get() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        Card.aggregate([
            { $sample: {size: Number(req.body.wordCount)} }, 
            { $match:  {"deckId": new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.deckId)} }
        ]).exec(function(err,result){
            if(err){
                reject(err);
            }else{
                resolve(result)
            }
        });

    });
}
```